# inserting blob image to database using file upload in html / jsp

Tags: mysql, image, jsp

I am new to jsp.I have a table named `employee` now I want to insert image to datatase using a name as `request` parameter.The table already have `name`,`age`,`id`,`phonenumber`,`email`,`password` as fields.image is my new field I created now.When updating image field with new blob image it is not showing error but image is not inserting. Here's my try :

```
    // My form to fileupload

    <form name="frm" action="Image.jsp"  method="post">
        <center>Name:<input type="text" name="name"><br></center><br>

     <center><br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Submit"></center>
   </form>

    //(Image.jsp )My pgogram to get file from client and store in database 

     <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
     <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.*"%>
     <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.io.output.*"%>
     <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*"%>
     <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*"%>
     <%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
 <%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
  <html>
      <body>
    <%
        Connection connection = null;
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/praveen";
        PreparedStatement pstatement = null;
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        int insertQuery = 0;

         byte[] b = null;

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "bulbultara");

         String sql = "update employee set image=? where name=? ";
        pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstatement.setString(2, request.getParameter("name"));
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

         ServletFileUpload sfu = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
         List items = sfu.parseRequest(request);

        Iterator iter = items.iterator();

         while (iter.hasNext()) {
         FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
         if (!item.isFormField()) {
         b = item.get();
            }
           }

        pstatement.setBytes(1, b);
        insertQuery = pstatement.executeUpdate();
        pstatement.close();
        connection.close();

      %>

       <a href="Login.jsp"><input type="submit" value="Login"></a>
     </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: do you know about `servlet` and `hibernate`. read about them they shud make things easier for you ?

Comment: you might wanna have a look at it : http://www.codejava.net/coding/upload-files-to-database-servlet-jsp-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <% @ page import="java.io.*" %>
   <% @ page import="java.sql.*" %>
   <% @ page import="java.util.zip.* "%>
  <%
     String saveFile="";
     String contentType=request.ContentType();
     if((contentType != null) &&(contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data")>=0))
      {
       DataInputStream in= new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
      int formDataLength=request.getContentLength();
      byte dataBytes[]= new byte[formDataLength];
      int byteread=0;
      int totalbyteread=0;
      while(totalbyteread<formDataLength)
      {
      byteread=in.read(dataBytes,totalbyteread,formDataLength);
      totalbyteread =byteread+1;
       }
      String file= new String(dataBytes);
      saveFile=file.subString(file.indexOf("filename=\"")+10);
       saveFile= saveFile.subString(0,saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
        saveFile=saveFile.subString(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\")+1,saveFile.indexOf("\""));

      int lastIndex=contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
      String boundry=contentType.subString(lastIndex+1,contentType.length());
      int pos;
      pos=file.indexOf("filename=\"");
      pos=file.indexOf("n\",pos)+1;
      pos=file.indexOf("n\",pos)+1;
      pos=file.indexOf("n\",pos)+1;
      pos=file.indexOf("n\",pos)+1;
      int boundrylocation=file.indexOf(boundry,pos)-4;
      int startpos=((file.subString(0,pos)).getBytes()).length;
      int endpos=((file.subString(0,boundryloction)).getBytes()).length;
      File ff= new File(saveFile);
      FileOutputStream fileout= new FileOutputStram(ff);
      fileout.write(dataBytes,startpos,(endpos-startpos));
      fileout.flush();
      fileout.close();
      %>
      <Br><table border="2"><tr><td><b>You have successfully upload the file:</b>
     <%out.println(saveFile);%></td></tr></table>
     <%
     Connection connection = null;
    String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/praveen";
    PreparedStatement pstatement = null;
    FileInputStream inputStream = fis;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    try
     {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "bulbultara");
     File f= new File(saveFile);
     pstatement=connection.prepareStatement("insert into employee(name of image cloumn) values(?)");
      pstatement.setBinaryStream(1, (InputStream)fis, (int)(f.length()));
     int s = pstatement.executeUpdate();
         if(s>0){
           System.out.println("Uploaded successfully !");
       }
      else{
      System.out.println("Error!");
       }
          }
        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
      }
     }

   %>
```